# Can't open Folder Options from Control Panel. How to fix this?

Tags: windows-xp, control-panel

I'm running Windows XP Pro SP2.
As the question says, I can't open "Folder Options" from "Control Panel".
I can, however, access "Folder Options" from the Tools menu in Windows Explorer.

Nothing happened when I double-clicked "Folder Options" in "Control Panel". Right-click then select "Open" didn't do anything either. No errors, warnings, or alerts at all. I'm using an administrator-equivalent user account with no password set.

I did a full scan with Avast 4.8 and it detected nothing on my PC. Left me wondering what caused this.

**Edit** - I use bbLean 1.17 as shell, which is apparently the source of the problem. As pointed out by John T.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also open it from the `Run` dialog.

try:

```
control folders
```

calling Dllregisterserver also usually fixes weird problems like these, try:

```
regsvr32 /i shell32.dll
```

Comment: Tried that, nothing happened.

Oh, and I used bbLean as shell.

Comment: There have been a lot of problems regarding bblean with windows explorer. A problem somewhat like yours is found here: http://www.lostinthebox.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7915

Comment: @Cliche7: That is important information that you ought to mention in your question.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that. Man, I've been googling about this folder options problem to no avail. John got the answer. Thank you very much.